# Minimising sum of an array using DP given a pattern in index

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, data-structures, dynamic-programming

Given an array containing `N` numbers we have to minimise the sum such that `index i<j<k<l` 
and there is an equation 
`A[l]-A[k]+A[j]-A[i]`.

I used 4 DP tables to solve it. In the first table I minimised the `A[l]` and in the second one minimised `A[l]-A[k]`, third table minimised `A[l]-A[k]+A[j]`, fourth one minimized `A[l]-A[k]+A[j]-A[i]`.

But I am confused about how can I find the original index `i, j, k, l` from these tables. Can someone please explain with the code by running on any sample array?

Comment: I don't understand the problem.  What is meant by 'Given an array containing "N" numbers we have to minimise the sum such that >index ito solve it`?  So you have an array of size N, you're trying to find the minimum sum with some constraint.  What's the constraint?

Comment: @DarrylG , somebody edited the question and formatting is little wrong. please ignore the >index  (ignore the > sign before index). Basically one has to minimize the some combination of sum in the array where indices i<j<k<l is strictly obeyed.

Comment: Max size of the array?

Comment: This looks like finding 2 closest pairs.

Comment: @vivek_23  please check now